# do I need separate UILabel in a custom UIView to have separate UILabel lines in a UITableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

do I need separate UILabel in a custom UIView to have separate UILabel lines in a UITableViewCell?

That is, if I want to have a TableViewCell that has all text, but the text needs to contain 4 separate rows for 4 separate strings (e.g. Name, Title, Description, Location), and each these separate rows could include a wrap around.

To ask the question the other way around, is there way with a normal UITableViewCell using it content view and single text label, to force Carriage Return/New Line points at the end of each of the four strings?  Oh yes, and the cell height will need to be calculated for each Cell as it may vary (just in case this is significant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the last question: NO.  (Answer to the title: YES.)

You can build a cell in its own NIB file.  An exercise I suggest if you've never done it.

Layout the size/location/resize functionality as you like it.

your table view controller can be the owner of the file,
add an outlet to the TV controller of `loadedCell`, and call load nib 
every time you want to alloc a new cell,

i suggest tagging each of the cell labels, and accessing them
that way, and setting the `loadedCell` value to `nil` after loading it,

p.s. a `UILabel` often wraps text undesirably, or is hard to layout in a cell to look good, consider the other values of `lineBreakMode` for your labels

p.p.s. it will employ a text shortening behavior depending on `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` and `minimumFontSize` (taking this and `lineBreakMode` into consideration)

Comment: p.p.p.s you can set the "reuse identifier" in the NIB file, or programmatically once loaded, but it should be set!  doing so in code helps ensure that you're using the same value as the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`